# On WSL2 Ubuntu doesn't recognize my clang installition from yesterday

Tags: ubuntu, clang, wsl-2

I've ran into some weird problem with clang. Yesterday I downloaded the precompiled binaries from the official clang/LLVM github repo - version 15.0.6 - . I managed to install it - unzipped it, extracted from tar, and copied the whole folder into /usr/local/ and add it to the $PATH variable - and when i ran the command `clang --version`, the output was that i have clang 15.0.6 on my system with of course an appropriate version of LLVM. Was very happy, PC shutdown, go to sleep.

Today I wanted to try out and compile a c++ source file.

Input: clang++ file.cpp -o file
Output: Command 'clang' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install clang

Ran clang --version, same answer as above. No clang, no LLVM, nothing! The folder, which i downloaded is still in /usr/local though. Since yesterday I have updated nothing at all! What could happenned at night??

Thanks in advance for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok! I finded out what was the error. When I added the file path to the $PATH  variable, I simply just typed the command - export PATH=$PATH:the/file/path - in the commandline. But so this is just temporary. When you start a new shell session the $PATH variable going to reset itself. To make it permanently you have to put the line into *bashrc*.

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Go down, the end of the file,

```
export PATH=$PATH:the/file/path
```

and finally

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

This will apply the changes to the current session.